# fisher.test() and Chi-square bug in R

Tags: r, fishers-exact-test

I'm getting this error when conducting fisher.test() in R:

```
freqTable = 
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 1 14  0  2  0  0  0  0
 2  0  0  0  9  0  0  0
 3  0  6  0  0  0  0  0
 4  0  0  0  0  6  0  0
 5  0  0  0  0  0 10  0
 6  0  0 10  0  0  0  0
 7  2  4  9  1  0  0 30

> fisher.test(freqTable, workspace=2e+07,hybrid=TRUE)$p.value
Error in fisher.test(freqTable, workspace = 2e+07, hybrid = TRUE) : 
  FEXACT error 30.
Stack length exceeded in f3xact.
This problem should not occur.
```

Chi-square is also problematic:

```
chisq.test(freqTable)

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  freqTable
X-squared = 466.81, df = 36, p-value < 2.2e-16

Warning message:
In chisq.test(freqTable) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Looks like there's an open bug report: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1662

I'm wondering if anyone has found an appropriate workaround for these cases?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried simulation instead? Don't ask for a hybrid approach--it does nothing different--but specify `simulate.p.value=TRUE` as per the manual page.

Answer (score 3):

I have now addressed this problem (and similar ones) in `fisher.test()`, and indeed fixed the bug (for "R-devel" only, see the bugs.r-project.org link above).
 Increasing 'workspace' now *does* help in fisher.test().... but this example takes a lot of time, if you run the exact test  (default hybrid=FALSE):

On machines with enough Giga bytes (4 GB free is ok):

```
system.time( ## -> takes much more time: 1 h 47 min !!!
ftL <- fisher.test(freqTable, workspace = 6e8))
##     user   system  elapsed -- ada-16, 2017-09-07
## 6422.367    4.611 6438.832  == 1 h 47 min
ftL
##  Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
##
## data:  freqTable
## p-value < 2.2e-16
## alternative hypothesis: two.sided
dput(ftL$p.value)
## 2.65517303157606e-49
```

I have not had the patience to also try the `hybrid=TRUE` case .. it 
may take less than the 1h 47min of the exact case.

Statistically, the answers above of course are sufficient and indeed, in many such cases, to use `simulate.p.value = TRUE` is more realistic here.

Answer (score 2):

There's no bug in the `chisquare.test` function; it's simply giving your a warning about low expected values (the chi-square approximation isn't so good when the expected values are small).

As whuber suggested you can use simulated p-values - but there's little point, the statistic is very large and it will obviously reject at whatever your significance level might be. But let's see:

For example:

```
chisq.test(freqTable,simulate=TRUE,B=1000000)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 1e+06 replicates)

data:  freqTable
X-squared = 466.81, df = NA, p-value = 1e-06
```

indicates that the p-value is smaller than $10^{-6}$ (because I only did $10^6$ simulations here and the sample value itself is included in the p-value calculations, so it can't figure it out to be smaller than that). When it gives a p-value of $1/m$ when you did $m$ simulations, it's typically more of an upper bound on the real p-value.